# maximin nonlinear optimization

Tags: optimization

Can someone give me an idea on how to solve the following maximin optimization

$\max_{p_i} min_ {i}  (w_i log_2(1+\frac{h_i p_i}{\sum_{j \neq i h_jp_j}+}+\sigma^2)-\lambda p_ig_i)$

$0 < p_i <  \frac{\lambda}{h_i}(\frac{w_ih_i}{\lambda g_i}-\sum_{j \neq i  }h_j p_j-\sigma^2)$

I have tried to solve only minimum function in matlab using `fmincon`, but I dont know how to solve a maximin optimization function.

Comment: multiply by -1?

Answer (score 1):

To solve $\max_{x} \min_i f_i(x)$, write as $\max_{x,t} t$ subject to $f_i(x)\geq t$.